# Very strange network behavior (perfect HTTP at 50% ping losses for specific Ethernet card)

Tags: ethernet

I'm dealing with Ethernet networks since 1989 and I believed I had seen it all when a few days ago I had this really strange experience that first I have to share with someone and second I'd love to get feedback If anybody has seen anything similar or if you can you think of any other troubleshooting trick or workaround I could try.

**The issue**

I had two different Oxygen ADSL modem/routers to connect to a PC running pfsense(a FreeBSD based firewall/router). The PC had an HP NC364T quad Ethernet Card that I had used time and time again in the past. All seemed good but I then noticed this bizarre behavior: I could browse the Internet **without any delay** but ping was giving me a 40-50% packet loss no matter from where and to where I was pinging. Pinging the IP of the ADSL modem from the pfsense PC: 40-50% loss. Pinging from any other PC behind pfsense to any Internet host: 40-50% loss.  I know that HTTP can withstand some packet loss but at 40 to 50% it should have been at least painfully slow if not totally unusable. And a RDP connection I tried was also snappy!!! It's as if the incompatibility affected only ICMP traffic.

**Things I tried that had no effect**

I Changed the cable & the card with another one of the same maker/model and then changed both once more (in total I tried 3 different cards and cables all of them where later proven to work just fine in another setup). Changed the settings for the Ethernet speed to 100Mbit/FD on both the modem and the HP Card. The whole time I was testing with either one or the other or both modem models.

**Either of these changes was fixing the issue**

1. changing from HP NC364T to cheap LAN cards
2. changing the modem to a third model -- again Oxygen but not
   exactly the same model with any of the other two
3. inserting a switch between the router and the PC.

**Epilogue**

It seems that these two specific Oxygen models don't want to talk to this specific LAN card model directly. If it was one modem/router model I would have been less surprised but hitting two cases on the same day seems a very strange coincidence. And the bizarre phenomenon of 50% ping losses while at the same time happily browsing at full speed really drives me insane.

Comment: This sounds like a common routing / duplex problem within your box, it's also quite easy to recreate / force. Loading a website wont really be affected by a 50% package loss, if you want to really see a difference start a VoIP UDP stream. Here 50% loss will be VERY visible.

Comment: Thanks for your time @cristian-matthias-ambæk. What common routing / duplex problem were you thinking about? Note that I tried manually setting both sides to 100Mbit/Full Duplex. Also I can't believe there's no difference in loading bing.com and using RDP with 50% packet loss.Think about half of your DNS queries and HTTP GETs timing out. And I often notice the lag in lines with 10 - 20% loss.

Comment: I have seen this on Linux OS when you have more than two routes to the same destination, even if they have their own routing entries, Cisco equipment with a duplex mismatch, Cisco equipment with a routing configuration error, example summarised routes as i recall. If you really think that their is package loss try and investigate further with for example Wireshark. If their is a package loss in only a specific type of packages maybe it's a firewall issue somewhere?

Comment: We can rule out routing & firewall errors because they wouldn't go away by inserting a switch. And I see now what you mean by duplex mismatch but it was one of the 1st settings I tried. Nevertheless again thanks for your time!

Comment: If you want a more direct answer i need more data :) Like a tcpdump, a network diagram or something in that regard